# SQL Server: how to increase the number of error logs files through tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-log

SQL Server:

- Environment: huge (multiple SQL versions, named instances, etc...)

How to increase the number of error logs files through T-SQL to a defined value? 
The scripts I found concern only the default instance and don't check for the current value of num. of error logs in place.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> USE master 
> GO 
> EXEC sys.xp_instance_regwrite
>   N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
>    ,N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'
>    ,N'NumErrorLogs'
>    ,REG_DWORD
>    ,20
> ```

The above code will create 20 error logs

Comment: Problem with xp_instance_regwrite permissions because service account is not local admin.

Answer (score 0):

--I found this way working with all versions:

USE master
go

```
Declare @instance_name nvarchar(100)                        
Declare @system_instance_name nvarchar(100)                        
Declare @key nvarchar(1000)                        
Declare @registry_key nvarchar(100)                        
Declare @NBRofErrorLogs int                        
Declare @NewValue int

SET @NewValue = 12

Set @instance_name= coalesce(convert(nvarchar(100), serverproperty('InstanceName')),'MSSQLSERVER');                        
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL', @instance_name, @system_instance_name output;                        

SET @registry_key = N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + @system_instance_name + '\MSSQLServer';                        
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',@registry_key,@value_name='NumErrorLogs',@value=@NBRofErrorLogs OUTPUT                        

IF isnull(@NBRofErrorLogs,6) < @NewValue
    EXECUTE [master].[sys].xp_regwrite --[xp_instance_regwrite]
       @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
      ,@key = @registry_key
      ,@value_name = N'NumErrorLogs'
      ,@type = N'REG_DWORD'
      ,@value = @NewValue;


EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',@registry_key,@value_name='NumErrorLogs',@value=@NBRofErrorLogs OUTPUT                        
select @NBRofErrorLogs
```